# Error occurred in deployment step Install SharePoint Add-in: Completion of the current operation would have caused the directory quota to be exceeded

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2019, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk-.net, azure-emulator

I am getting this error -

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Install SharePoint Add-in': Completion of the current operation would have caused the directory quota to be exceeded.

while trying to locally debug an Azure cloud service (classic). Can anyone point me right direction on fixing this issue?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Our SharePoint admin team contacted Microsoft and the object quota for the tenant has been increased by Microsoft which fixed this issue with local debugging using Azure Emulator.